# reactjs value returning [object Object]

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I've been working on some ReactJS code, where when a button is pressed a single value is passed on.

The code is mostly working fine, except that when trying to pass the value from the `<li>` element, it passes `[object Object]`.

```
var React = require("react");
var { Panel } = require("react-bootstrap");

var JobStore = require("../stores/JobStore");

export var Spiderslist = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
    return {value: ""};
    },


render: function () {
    var ulStyle = {
    listStyleType: "none",
    padding: "0px",
    margin: "0px"
    };

    var noPadding = {paddingLeft: 0,    paddingRight:0,marginLeft:0,marginRight: 0};
    var splst = this.props.splst;
    var Lst = <ul style={ulStyle}>
    {splst.map(function(listValue , i){
    return <li><button type="submit" style={{marginBottom:"1%"}}
ref="domainInput" name="domain" value={listValue} className="btn btn-  success" key={i}>{listValue}</button></li>; # This is where the value returns Object inside value={listValue} but text renders fine.
       })}
    </ul>;
    return (
    <form method="post" className="container-fluid" style={noPadding}    action=   {this.props.runner} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    <div className="col-xs-10" style={noPadding} onClick={this.onClick}>
        {{Lst}}
         </div>
    </form>
    );
},

onClick: function (ev) {
    this.setState({value: this.refs.domainInput.getDOMNode().value});
},

onSubmit: function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    JobStore.Actions.startCrawl(this.state.value);
    this.setState({value: ""});
}
});
```

The issue seems to lie where I set the button's value, at `value={listValue}` in the button. How can I get the string value?

Comment: can u do JSON.stringify(listvalue) and share the result once?

Comment: `var splst = this.props.splst;` after this like do a `console.log(splst)`, check is it iterable, if not then go to parent which is passing props, do `console.log` and keep filter props till props become an array.

Comment: @Harkirat Saluja This dose return the value in the array but always just the first in the list no matter what value i click on. However value={listValue.name} returns the correct value and not the object. But always the first in the list and not the actual value i click on. o the problem has changed.

Comment: value={JSON.stringify(listValue.name)} works. Thanks for the help